# How to add manufacturer specific data in advertise packets for nordic nrf82532

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a need to code in manufacture specific data in NRF ble advertisement packets> I need to do so to make an additional ble test kit for testing my main device(which is probably filtering blue tooth packets based on company id and specific data ).

I have tried to modify the sample from the SDK BLE-Peripheral_UART (deemed to be easiest to fit my need). However I bumped into problem of adding company specific data.

Below is how i added my data

```
uint8_t COMPANY_ID[] = { 0x99, 0x99};
uint8_t COMPANY_DATA[] = {0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x72, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x00};

static const struct bt_data ad[] = {
    BT_DATA_BYTES(BT_DATA_FLAGS, (BT_LE_AD_GENERAL | BT_LE_AD_NO_BREDR)),
    BT_DATA(BT_DATA_MANUFACTURER_DATA, COMPANY_ID, 2),
    BT_DATA(BT_DATA_MANUFACTURER_DATA,COMPANY_DATA,8),
    BT_DATA(BT_DATA_NAME_COMPLETE, DEVICE_NAME, DEVICE_NAME_LEN),
};
```

The result however shown something like this
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
But I need it to be like this

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I believe somehow I have used the wrong function... but there is no simple api (the documentation was mind-boggling) for me to read. Need some help for pointing me in the direction where i can get the information from or any help

Thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3Vv3.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKPHD.png

## EDIT

Btw in response to fabik111 queries, I am using

1. Nordic UART Bridge Service (NUS) sample from SDK v1.7.0
2. I am passing the ad (advertisement) and scan response (sd) data by `err = bt_le_adv_start(BT_LE_ADV_CONN, ad, ARRAY_SIZE(ad), sd, ARRAY_SIZE(sd));`

Comment: Which SDK version are you using? Which api function do you pass the `ad` array? Have you checked that the advertise data length does not exceed the limit of 31 bytes?

Comment: @fabik111 I am using Nordic UART Bridge Service (NUS) sample from SDK v1.7.0.. I am passing the ad (advertisement) and scan response (sd) data by  err = bt_le_adv_start(BT_LE_ADV_CONN, ad, ARRAY_SIZE(ad), sd,
         ARRAY_SIZE(sd));

Answer (score 0):

I believe I might have got it working ...

```
uint8_t COMPANY_ID[] = { 0x99, 0x99, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x72, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x00};

static const struct bt_data ad[] = {
    BT_DATA_BYTES(BT_DATA_FLAGS, (BT_LE_AD_GENERAL | BT_LE_AD_NO_BREDR)),
    BT_DATA(BT_DATA_MANUFACTURER_DATA, COMPANY_ID, 10),
    BT_DATA(BT_DATA_NAME_COMPLETE, DEVICE_NAME, DEVICE_NAME_LEN),
};
```